# How to find percentage value from a table column

Tags: php, mysql, percentage

I am trying to find the a percentage value of every numeric value with the same id in my table. For example, if my table consists of this:

```
id  answer          points
1   answer 1        3
1   answer 2        1
1   answer 3        10
1   answer 4        5
1   answer 5        6
1   answer 6        10
1   answer 7        10
1   answer 8        2
```

If max points are 80, how can I display the current result (point) from database in percentage form?

Answer (score 2):

Sum() the points and divide them by 80:

```
select id, sum(points), sum(points)/80 as percentage
from table
group by id
```

Comment: How do I show this in a webpage using PHP?

Comment: Execute the query, loop through the results and display them in whatever format you would like them to.

Comment: Like this? http://codepad.viper-7.com/ppk9u6

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
select   100 * (points / 80) as Percentage
from     YourTable
```

You could even consider calculating the total number of points:

```
select   100 * (points / (select sum(points) from YourTable)) as Percentage
from     YourTable
```

That way, you can just add answers to the table, and the calculation will adjust accordingly.

Comment: How do I show this in a webpage using PHP?

Comment: [That's a good question for the beginner's tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GROUP BY` for this purpose like

```
select maxpoint * 0.1 as maxpoint_percent
from (
select id, sum(points) as maxpoint
from table1
group by id ) xx
where maxpoint >= 80;
```

Comment: How do I show this in a webpage using PHP?